# error in new line in equation,displaying >= and || ||

Tags: equations

While typing the equation, I am getting an error. Further `norm` and `greater than` and `equalto` are not displayed

```
\begin{equation}
x which maximize    \frac{2}{‖g‖}
\newline such that y  (g^T x + b) ≥ 1
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a *full compilable* code which reproduces the problem. Anyway `equation` is a single line environment.

Comment: You're using unicode symbols which you can't do without loading the package `unicode-math`.  In normal LaTeX you would need to replace ≥ with `\geq` and ‖g‖ should probably be `\lVert g \rVert`

Answer (score 3):

As @Au101 has already observed in a comment, you need to either switch to a unicode-math compatible typesetting engine -- the LuaLaTeX format and the `unicode-math` package come to mind -- or write `\lVert` and `\rVert` instead of `‖` and write `\ge` (or `\geq`) instead of `≥`. Encasing the text-mode word snippets in `\text` directives would also be a good idea.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
with unicode symbols:
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
x \text{ which maximizes }   \frac{2}{‖g‖} \\
\text{such that } y  (g^T x + b) ≥ 1
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
without unicode symbols:
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
x \text{ which maximizes }   \frac{2}{\lVert g\rVert} \\
\text{such that } y  (g^T x + b) \ge 1
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \begin{split}
    x\text{ which maximize }   \frac{2}{\lVert g\rVert}\\
s.t~y~(g^\top x + b) \geq1
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Instead of writing `~\text{which maximize} ~`, consider writing `\text{ which maximize }`.

Comment: @Mico Could you explain me what the difference would be?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the clarification, now I understand. I have also edited my snippet accordingly.

Comment: @Mico I don't see David's comment, could you explain what that was?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! David made a comment on a (since-deleted) comment of mine, in which I elaborated on my initial claim that `\text{ which maximize }` was preferable to `~\text{which maximize} ~`. David pointed out that this claim was only  partially correct. Specifically, writing `\text{ which maximize }` does indeed ensure that the three interword whitespaces are the same, but it does not help in case LaTeX needs to shrink the amount of interword whitespace. That's why I chose to delete the comment. I should probably delete the initial comment too, right?!

Comment: @Mico I know the first part of conversation :) Today morning, I woke up and saw a lot things happened, I was lost in the middle. Nevertheless, IMO, atleast for future references, I would like the comments to be retained (ofcourse, if you agree with that too). I think most of the learning is from feedback :P

Comment: Thanks. I won't delete either of my two earlier comments, then. (And I'll leave this one intact too...)